# What tools are used in animal cloning?

Tags: embryology, cloning, cytogenetics, development

So I was reading up on articles to do a project about cloning but there were no places in the article where It states the tool used to take the gene out of the nucleus and insert it into plasmids ? can anyone accurately tell me what the tool is. I don't mean the process but the actual names of the tools like CRISPR etc.

As a reference The article was the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloning

Comment: biolistic particle delivery system, TALEN (Transcription activator-like effector nuclease), Homing endonuclease

Comment: What kind of cloning are you interested in. Gene cloning can be done in plasmids using restriction endonucleases also. You have to add specifics.

Comment: About cloning a whole new animal

Comment: @hoodlamic1 Cloning a new animal is done using a technique called [Somatic Cell Nuclear Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_cell_nuclear_transfer). Is that what you are interested in? Can you add more details? Molecular cloning is different and your question and your comment are conflicting each other.